# XCode 4: Get device name / id and save to NSString?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, nsstring

How can I save the device name to an NSString and work with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to read `name` property via `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]`. It'll return string.
Get familiar with UIDevice class [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html), it offers a lot and remember: documentation is your friend :)

Comment: NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]; throws some warnings?

Comment: @Martin: it should not, however the only warning you can possibly get here is when `deviceName` variable is not used in the scope where it's defined.

Comment: i want it utf8 encoded but umlaute like ü and so on are not delivered right  i get Ã¼ instead of ü

Comment: How and where do you use your `deviceName`? Normally, all language specific sign should be ok. Try NSLog on `deviceName` and put it into a text view to double-check...